# Trying to understand RSACryptoServiceProvider key and message length relationship

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to better understand the cryptography classes in .Net and I have a situation that I do not understand clearly. I'm following a stripped down version of this [RSACryptoServiceProvider example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8#examples).

my shortened version is this:

```
string plainText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dapibus.";
var byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

//Works with longer string length
using var rsa = RSA.Create();
byte[] encrypted2 = rsa.Encrypt(byteConverter.GetBytes(plainText), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);

//fails if string's length is too long
using var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] encrypted = rsa2.Encrypt(byteConverter.GetBytes(plainText), false);
```

If you cut the string off at "elit" like so:

```
string plainText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
```

then both work.

When I use the provider's overload constructor and give it an ample key size like so:

```
using var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
```

then it can encrypt the full string's length.

What is the relationship between the key size and message length? What's the best way to determine what size key I need and why does the RSA. Create a method have no issues with the string's length?

Comment: Would [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172) answer your question? Note that although you're using .NET, the size in bytes that can be encrypted is not runtime specific.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ... that looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Note that may runtimes only allow e.g. 32 bit increments. Using 2048 or 3072 rather than 2056 seems a lot more logical. For software implementations the larger bit size should not be much of an issue. 1024 bits should really not be used anymore.

Comment: Oh yes, I did put that number in rather arbitrarily just trying to get the string to work and wasn't thinking about it from that perspective. For the record this is just me playing around with .Net classes and not work related.

Comment: Playing around is always a good excuse :)

Comment: That link you gave certainly gives me what I was looking for. If you want to put it in an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` simply implements the schemes as specified in PKCS#1 v2.0 and beyond (PKCS#1 2.2 being the current version). I've specified the overhead and left over payloads [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172). It's language / runtime agnostic.

Although PKCS#1 v1.5 padding has less overhead, OAEP is more secure (it has a security proof for RSA) and should normally be used. PKCS#1 v1.5 only has 11 overhead bytes for a random component of 61 bits total. However, good practice would really require double the random component - for an overhead of 11 + 8 = 19 bytes.